# How can I search and execute two scripts simultaneously in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, sh, aix

Suppose you have a folder that contains two files.

Example: `stop_tomcat_center.sh` and `start_tomcat_center.sh`.

In my example, the return of `ls *tomcat*` returns these two scripts.
How can I search and execute these two scripts simultaneously?

I tried

```
ls *tomcat* | xargs sh
```

but only the first script is executed (not the second).

Comment: Stopping and starting tomcat at the same time doesn't seem that sensible...

Comment: You can use the `at` UNIX feature.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do multiple things in parallel is with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel ::: ./*tomcat*
```

Or, if your scripts don't have a shebang at the first line:

```
parallel bash ::: ./*tomcat*
```

---

Or if you like `xargs`:

```
ls *tomcat* | xargs -P 2
```

Answer (score 1):

xargs is missing the `-n 1` option.

From `man xargs`:

> -n max-args, --max-args=max-args
>
> Use at most max-args arguments per command line. Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.

xargs otherwise tries to execute the command with as many parameters as possible, which makes sense for most commands.

In your case `ls *tomcat* | xargs sh` is running `sh stop_tomcat_center.sh start_tomcat_center.sh` and the stop_tomcat_center.sh is probably just ignoring the `$1` parameter.

---

Also it is not a good idea to use the output of ls. A better way would be to use `find -maxdepth 1 -name '*tomcat*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sh` or `for command in *tomcat*; do sh "$command"; done`

---

**This answer is based on the assumption that the OP meant "both with one command line" when he wrote "simultaneously".**

For solutions on parallel execution have take a look at the other answers.

Comment: for parallel execution you would need `| xargs -n1 -Px`, where `x` is desired concurrency, I think.

Comment: @bobah I am sure the OP did not mean "parallel" when he wrote "simultaneously", he just meant both with one command line. (wouldn't make much sence running stop/start parallel)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to search and execute

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec sh x {} \;
```

find will find the file and exec will find the match and execute